# Sorted dictionary returns NoneType instead of list?

Tags: python, dictionary, nonetype

So, I am trying to write a program to read in a text file, then remove stopwords, then find the most common words and write them to a dictionary, then sort the dictionary.

It seems that I am able to find the most common words just fine, but when I sort the dictionary to display most found words first, NoneType is returned instead of list and I get a TypeError. Why is that?

```
import string

#Read in book and stopwords (lower case)
sense_and_sensibility_dirty = open("Sense_and_Sensibility.txt").read().rstrip("\n")
stop_words = open("stopwords.txt").read().split()
stop_words = [x.lower() for x in stop_words]

#Remove punctuation from the book and clean it up
translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
sns = sense_and_sensibility_dirty.translate(translator)
sns = sns.split()

#Convert words in book to lowercase
sns = [x.lower() for x in sns]
#Remove stop words from book
sns = [x for x in sns if x not in stop_words]

#Count up words in the book and write word and count to dictionary
word_count={}
for word in sns:
    if word not in word_count:
        word_count[word] = 1
    else:
        word_count[word] += 1

#Sort the dictionary to display most frequent
e = sorted(word_count.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])
e = e.reverse()
e[:4]
```

For example, e[:4] should output something like:

```
[('time', 237), ('dashwood', 224), ('sister', 213), ('miss', 209)]
```

but instead I get:

```
"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable".
```

Comment: `reverse` returns `None` , it works inplace.

Comment: `e = e.reverse()` Methods such as reverse will return a None. Do not assign method calls that modify inplace. use just `e.reverse()`

Comment: Never mind, I found out I simply shouldn't assign e to e.reverse().

Answer (score 2):

`lst.reverse` is a mutable operation and returns `None`, you should not reassing the variable:

```
e = sorted(word_count.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])
e.reverse()
e[:4]
```

Comment: This is also in python 3.

Comment: @rassar you are right, I was thinking about sorted returning a list instead in python2 and mixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this helps !! include the reverse= True in the sorted method itself

```
from string import punctuation
from collections import Counter

with open('Sense_and_Sensibility.txt','r') as f:
    sense_and_sensibility_dirty = f.read()

with open('stopwords.txt','r') as f:
    stopwords = f.read().split()
stop_words = [x.lower() for x in stop_words]

sense_and_sensibility_dirty = sense_and_sensibility_dirty.lower()
all_text = ''.join([c for c in sense_and_sensibility_dirty if c not in punctuation])

sense_and_sensibility_dirty_split = all_text.split('\n')
all_text = ' '.join(sense_and_sensibility_dirty_split)
words = all_text.split()
req_words = [word for word in words if word not in stop_words]

word_counts = Counter(req_words)
sorted_words = sorted(word_counts, key = word_counts.get, reverse= True)
```